# Workflow approval task can’t update Current Item

Tags: tasks, item-level-permissions, approval

I have a document library with an associated InfoPath form for users to enter time worked on/in.  On submission a workflow starts, this collects information from the form (loads to variables) and then starts an approval task…

The library has 2 groups, ‘Timesheet Users’ and ‘Timesheet Approvers’

Just before the task starts the delete permission for ‘Timesheet Users’ is applied to the item so the file can’t be edited (this step is new). FYI I have tried delete permission and then grant read to the item but it didn’t work

Upon approval or rejection the workflow updates an Audit Log list, the link between this list and the document library is the timesheet ID. This step works but I had to make a change as ‘Current Item:ID’ that was used to find the respective item in the audit log stopped working. (I created a new variable for the ID before starting the task). I should point out that it worked for me before the fix (probably because I am a site admin).

When the item is Rejected there is an additional step that won’t work… I am trying to rename (using the ‘Path and Name’ field) the file in the document library so a new timesheet can be submitted. This used to work using Update ‘Current Item’ but since removing the users permission it does not.  I have Made a change so the Update doesn’t use the ‘Current Item’ reference, instead it updates the item in the document library by using the variable for the ID (as mentioned above).

This all works for me but not for the users.  Just above the update step I have tried several combinations of ‘Grant Permission’ back to the Users but none seem to work.  Given the workflow works for me (and any users that happen to also be in the Approvers group) I assume it must be permissions related but no idea what to do ‍♂️

Any help / ideas would be greatly appreciated.  I inherited the support of this process and this is not my field of expertise so all suggestions welcome.

I am using SharePoint 2013 to edit the workflow/task.  The steps to perform all of this are in the ‘Overall Task behaviour’-‘When task completes’ section of the task

If I have missed any important info please ask me…

Many thanks